# Convert tuple of dictionaries to dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is ordered tuple of dictionaries:

```
data = ({'a': 1}, {'b': 5}, {'c': 3})
```

How to right a code that makes dataframe with row for keys in dictionaries and column for values in dictionaries and another column for value difference between dictionaries like below:

```
      key  values  difference
0       a       1           1
1       b       5           4
2       c       3          -2
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
pd.Series(data).\
    apply(pd.Series).\
       stack().reset_index(level=1).\
          assign(diff=lambda x : x[0].diff().fillna(x[0]))
  level_1    0  diff
0       a  1.0   1.0
1       b  5.0   4.0
2       c  3.0  -2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`stack` + `diff` if none of your entries contain null values

---

```
u = pd.DataFrame([*data]).melt(var_name='key').dropna()

u.assign(difference=u.value.diff().fillna(u.value)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
  key  value  difference
0   a    1.0         1.0
1   b    5.0         4.0
2   c    3.0        -2.0
```